Cookie header not sent in Azure Load Testing URL-based test
I'm trying out Azure Load Testing and encounter the problem that, if I set up a URL-based test (the simple GUI-based way to set up load tests) with a Cookie header, the header isn't actually sent. Other headers are correctly sent.
In the example below, the server at https://example.org/requires_cookie receives calls with an OtherHeader header, but no Cookie header.

There are no validation errors, the test configuration saves and runs correctly, and when editing the test, the Cookie header is still shown in the panel that allows editing the request. Clicking the Copy as cURL button at the bottom of the panel copies a correct cURL command which includes the Cookie header:
curl --request GET 'https://example.org/requires_cookie' --header 'Cookie: foo=bar' --header 'OtherHeader: baz'

Switching to the Add cURL command request format and pasting in this correct cURL command saves and runs correctly, but still doesn't send the Cookie header.

Create a very basic test with just the URL and the Cookie header, no other headers or parameters. This will help isolate if the issue is specific to the Cookie header or if there are other factors involved.

@alex: This is the very basic reproduction case. Everything's default except for these headers. Removing OtherHeader doesn't affect anything. It's just there to show that it's specifically a problem with the Cookie header.

This seems to be a problem specifically with URL-based tests. Here's a section of the underlying JMX (Apache JMeter) test file that Azure Load Testing generates, which shows the missing Cookie header:
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="RequiresCookie">
  <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
  </elementProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/requires_cookie</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">example.org</stringProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
  <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testname="HTTP HeaderManager">
    <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
      <elementProp name="OtherHeader" elementType="Header">
        <stringProp name="Header.name">OtherHeader</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Header.value">baz</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
    </collectionProp>
  </elementProp>
</HTTPSamplerProxy>

A workaround is to set up the URL-based test, click the button to convert is to a JMX (JMeter) test, download the JMX test plan, edit it to add in the Cookie header in the HeaderManager.headers collection, then delete and reupload the edited file in the Azure Portal.
However, you then can't use the simple GUI anymore. You may instead consider creating a JMeter test directly.
